# bluetooth adaptor functions only on either of the operating system

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth

bluetooth adapter functions only on either of the operating system not on both with multi-booting of ubuntu13.10 and windows 7 and interestingly wifi is working well on both os

my machine is toshiba Satellite-c640

Comment: And the one it works in is....

Comment: either of them , but it works only on one OS